# Javascript variable lifecycle

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and I cannot understand why this code works:

```
function getObj()
{
   var objAddress = 
   {
      address: "Client Address",
      getAddress: function() {
         return this.address;
      },
      setAddress: function(newAddress)
      {
         this.address = newAddress;
      }
   };

   var objClient =
   {
      name: "Client name",
      getAddress: function()
      {
         return objAddress.getAddress();
      },
      setAddress: function(newAddress) {
         objAddress.setAddress(newAddress);
      }
   };

   return objClient;
}

gObj = getObj();
console.log(gObj.getAddress()); // Will print "Client Address"
gObj.setAddress("xpto");
console.log(gObj.getAddress()); // Will print "xpto"
```

I thought it would not work since `getAddress()` calls another method of an object that should not exist after leaving the function. But, as this is working, I presume that the object `objAddress` still exists even after quiting the `getObj` function.

Outside the function, how can the `gObj.getAddress()` work?

Comment: Read about closures, they are very important.

Comment: What makes you think the method `getAddress()` calls doesn't exist?

Comment: I came from C/C++ and, mistankenly,I think that, after the return statement, all the local variables of the function will be deleted. So, the objAddress will be deteled also.

Answer (score 3):

When you create function, which uses local variable, function "remembers" this local variable. All needed local variables are stored in special object called closure. You cannot directly access it, but function can.
Chrome Developer Tools in javascript debug shows closure object:[image: Closure in Chrome Developer Tools]

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **closure**. From [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

> variables from the parent function of the closure remain bound from the parent's scope. ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures))

That is to say, functions exist with a reference to the scope that they were defined in. As long as functions with a reference to the scope exist, the scope will exist.

Answer (score 0):

`getObj` is a closure and in here:

```
gObj = getObj();
```

gObj is an instance of that closure and so all functions and properties that are defined in that class is valid for oObj too.